# Error using mousemove out of the frame div tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sample code:

```
<div style="background: url('test.jpg') no-repeat left center; width: 500px; height: 334px;">
   <div id="button-wrapper" style="position: absolute; opacity: 1; z-index: 100;">
   <input type="button" value="submit">    
   </div>
</div>​
```

And Jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("div[id^=\'button-wrapper\']").parent().mousemove(function(e){
        jQuery("div[id^=\'button-wrapper\']").css({
            top:e.pageY-5,
            left:e.pageX-5
         });
    });
});​
```

Error when I mouse move out of the frame (div id="button-wrapper") it's run when out of frame, How to fix it, to only run in the frame ? (demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qCbwr/6/))

Comment: You could just use `$` instead of `jQuery` and if you want to refer to an element by id use `$("#button-wrapper")`

Answer (score 1):

Define the containment for mousemove in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link.. code updated...

[CHECK THIS LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/qCbwr/24/)

I had Added constraint on that mouse movemnet

```
 var a = $(this).height()-15;
         var b = $(this).width()-35;
        if(e.pageY < a&& e. pageX < b)
        {
        $('div[id^="button-wrapper"]').css({
                        top:e.pageY-5,
            left:e.pageX-5
         });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the mouse is being moved outside the parent div. See example at - http://jsfiddle.net/qCbwr/40/.

```
var _c = $(this);
var _p = _c.position();;

if (_top > (_p.top + _c.height())) _top = _p.top + _c.height();
if (_left > (_p.left + _c.width())) _left = _p.left +_c.width();
```

You will need to allow for the size of the button if you do not want the control to go outside the div entirely.